# Where is Hamster time tracker in Bionic?

Tags: 18.04, hamster

I can't find Hamster in the repositories for 18.04. Has this package been renamed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like `hamster-applet` got removed from the universe repository starting with Ubuntu 18.04:

[Ubuntu packages search results](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=hamster-applet&searchon=names)

This is probably related to their recent effort to completely refactor the application. You'll be able to find more info about their development status on the project homepages:

- https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Projects/ProjectHamster
- http://projecthamster.org/
- https://github.com/projecthamster

The GitHub repositories above should also contain downloadable packages or at least instructions on how to get and install the application, for both the original project and the rewrite.

---

**Update:** If you examine the search link above now, it looks like starting with Groovy (20.10), there is a `hamster-applet` package again, but it is only transitional and all it does is to install the new `hamster-time-tracker` package instead, which seems to be the same thing, just named differently? At least it's based on the same source.

Check [the package search results for that](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=hamster-time-tracker&searchon=names).

Comment: It looks like they are taking the project in a good direction. Unfortunately in the meantime the old one is broken and the new one isn't ready.

Comment: I managed to install hamster-lib and get hamster-cli working. It's a bit raw, but at least I can log events and dump to a csv file.

Comment: is there an update on this?

Comment: @PandianLe Apparently, yes. If you check the search page I linked in my answer, there's a new package now for 20.10 and newer. Updated my post.